# Parse numbers and string from string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, parsing

I have a strings such as

```
a = "3red12green7852purple"
```

I would like to parse `a` so that I have an array like this

```
[3,"red", 12, "green", 7852, "purple"]
```

Is it possible to do so using regexp in Ruby?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.html

Comment: @Paul That page gives you an incorrect impression that the linked pages will have code designed for use in R. Since those other pages do not perform the necessary double-escaping of regex meta-characters in the patterns, it's not going to be useful for inexperienced R-regex students.

Comment: that's not r code. perhaps you meant to tag python

Comment: @rawr not to mention, can't mix types in a vector

Comment: @rawr, yes sorry I was talking about Ruby!

Comment: When asking a question, we'd like to see your code, so we can see what you tried. Showing effort is really important on SO. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]".

Comment: Your question sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/153968), where you're asking about Y instead of X. A string like that is very uncommon. Where does it come from?

Comment: @theTinMan : Agree it's possibly an XY problem, but not that this sort of string is that rare.   The gtools package in R has `mixedsort` and `mixedorder` function` to handle just this sort of "mixture", which I suspect often gets produced by stumbling data entry processes on column names.

Comment: I'd like to see additional samples of the input also. If it's possible to parse by columns it's going to suggest different patterns.

Comment: @theTinMan, the number correspond to a time in sec, the color corresponds to a transit line. So `a` is a route. All routes are an output from a xls macro. `a` can also be a route for a driver between nodes. In that case, it'll be something like 31SBL1EBT220EBT. The numbers are actually id (I do not control the naming).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# letters followed by numbers or numbers followed by letters
your_regex <- "[A-Za-z]+(?=\\d|$)|\\d+(?=[A-Za-z]|$)"

unlist(str_extract_all(a, your_regex))

[1] "3"      "red"    "12"     "green"  "7852"   "purple"
```

Your question was originally tagged R. In Ruby (which I don't know) I think it would be something like

```
a.scan(/[A-Za-z]+(?=\d|$)|\d+(?=[A-Za-z]|$)/)
```

Comment: @C8H10N402 yes it was. But it's fine I decided to use R with your code. Thanks!

Comment: Ruby code works fine.

Comment: And also a.scan(/[A-Za-z]+(?=\d|$)|\d+(?=[A-Za-z]|$)/) is also working in Ruby

Comment: While the pattern works, it's very complicated. I'd use a simpler solution.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Unlike other answers, using `split` is the way to go here.

```
a.split(/(\D+)/)
# => ["3", "red", "12", "green", "7852", "purple"]

a.split(/(\D+)/).each_slice(2).flat_map{|i, s| [i.to_i, s]}
# => [3, "red", 12, "green", 7852, "purple"]
```

Comment: Another way on #2: `enum = [true, false].cycle; a.split(/(\D+)/).map { |o| enum.next ? o.to_i : o }`

Comment: Yes! I should have think of split. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This works as well, FWIW:

```
a.scan(/\D+|\d+/)
```

Comment: While your code works, you should provide more information. Show the result and WHY it's a better solution.